# Webpage very slow to print in IE

Tags: html, performance, printing, internet-explorer-8

For any of our HTML5 pages from our application (including a static HTML snapshot of a page):

When loading the print dialogue in IE (regardless of how you got there CTRL+P, rightclick->print, javascript->.print()) it can take a very long time to load.

I do have a print.css which display:none; much of the layout and extra parts of the page.

I'm expecting this to be a painful debug process, but I'd love any recommendations on where to start debugging for these symptoms.

- Is it likely to be the extra screen only CSS (which is large and complicated and largely irrelevant)?
- Is it likely to be the javascript assets?
- Any other things you'd recommend looking at (conditional IE statements, doctypes, etc)

Comment: It's likely to be related to the quality of the browser you're using ;-)

Comment: How are you implementing the print.css? I wasn't aware that IE8 supported CSS media queries for printing?

Comment: The browser is obviously the issue ( IE<* ). -- IE does suport media="print" for links to stylesheets (nothing in the CSS itself, to the best of my knowledge)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that the slowness was in fact due to the large CSS file, mentioned above... I change that to media="screen" so it wasn't loaded during the print queue and things speeded up significantly.

(the JS wasn't the issue)

Unfortunately, that means my print.css can't just hide and strip down the display, but now has to style things as well - but at least performance isn't taking a hit.